# Keyboard Press Detection with pynput

Tags: python, keyboard, pynput

```
from pynput import keyboard 

def on_press(key): 
    print('Key %s pressed' % key) 

def on_release(key): 
    print('Key %s released' %key) 

with keyboard.Listener( on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener: 
    listener.join()
```

if i keep pressing the F1 button and release,
it says

```
Key Key.f1 pressed
Key Key.f1 pressed
Key Key.f1 pressed
Key Key.f1 pressed
Key Key.f1 pressed
Key Key.f1 pressed
Key Key.f1 pressed
Key Key.f1 pressed
Key Key.f1 pressed
Key Key.f1 pressed
Key Key.f1 pressed
Key Key.f1 released
```

if i keep pressing the F1 button and release,i want it to work like below

```
Key Key.f1 pressed
Key Key.f1 released
```

Please help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pressed = False

def on_press(key): 
    global pressed
    if not pressed and key == keyboard.Key.f1: # only if key is not held
        print('Key %s pressed' % key) 
        pressed = True # key is held

def on_release(key):
    global pressed 
    if key == keyboard.Key.f1:
        print('Key %s released' %key) 
        pressed = False # key is released
```

Code is pretty self explanatory, you just provide a boolean `pressed` that whenever you press the `F1` key it is `True` and whenever you release it, it is `False`. If `press` is `False` you just ignore the `on_press` "signal".

if you want to achieve this with every key you'll have to store the state of every key in a dictionary (or as similar object).

```
pressed = {}

def on_press(key): 
    if key not in pressed: # Key was never pressed before
        pressed[key] = False
    
    if not pressed[key]: # Same logic
        pressed[key] = True
        print('Key %s pressed' % key) 

def on_release(key):  # Same logic
    pressed[key] = False
    print('Key %s released' %key)
```

Comment: I lay down to sleep. I will wake up and ask questions and close it.

Comment: @g0dst3r What do you mean, is there something unclear?

Comment: Can you apply it to all keys as well as F1?

Comment: @g0dst3r Yes, It's even easier that accessing individuals, updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

@Countour-Integral's answer is great, but here's another solution: wait until the key stops being pressed directly inside the function by using `keyboard`. This way, you can omit the global variables:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    print('f1 pressed')
    if key == Key.f1:
        while True:
            if not keyboard.is_pressed('f1'):
                break

def on_release(key):
    if key == Key.f1:
        print('f1 released')

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```